# Coroutines issues in scripts

Tags: c#-4.0, unity-game-engine

I am using Visual Studio 2013. When I use in code objects like **Action<T> or Func<T, TSource>** in unity i am getting error:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Action' from assembly 'mscorlib,    Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Func`1' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I tried to switch project to Framework 4.0, but that didn't helped. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "that didn't helped" - did it make any difference at all? And what framework were you targeting before? Do you know which version of the framework Unity3D supports?

Comment: I am using VS2013, so I targeted 4.5.1, 4.5, and 4.0. Unity supports 4.0 as far as I understood. Also what I tried was from working example tutorial.

Comment: Well if Unity only supports 4.0, there's no point in targeting 4.5 is there? It's not clear what you mean by targeting *3* versions. Are you sure the version of Unity *you're using* supports 4.0? If so, you should be able to just target 4.0 and it should be okay...

Comment: I think unity supports 3.5 target framework not 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK Unity only supports the Framework 2.0 with some of the 3.5 features.

In *Edit->Project Settings->Player->Other Settings* be sure to choose the full .NET 2.0 framework and not the subset.

**UPDATE** : In VS, you have to compile every DLL in 3.5.

Normally your code should work correctly.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Yep this will help. I use Action and Func all the time and it does require full .net 2.0.

Comment: That sounds even more odd to me... Action and Func were not available in .NET framework 2.0. Am I missing something generally?

Comment: That is more like CLR 2.0 rather than .net 2.0 If you google "unity mono .net versions" you will get a ton of resources explaining this mess in greater detail.

Comment: I added the comment regarding the compilation of the DLL that should be in 3.5